# SVG 3d rotation by X

Tags: 3d, svg, rotation

I'm trying to create 5 rectangles which are getting more and more rotated in the y-axis as they get far away from the centered rectangle.

But I can't get how to use the transform and perspective attributes to achieve it. I'm able only to rotate in 2d, but when I specify rotateY or rotateX it does not respond and stays the same.

any help? tutorial? example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's some good explanation on how to use perspective effects in SVG:
https://www.svgopen.org/2008/papers/86-Achieving_3D_Effects_with_SVG/#section_4_4_creating_perspective_effects_using_future_features

The page is from 2008 and they are talking about future and it appears as if this is not yet working in most SVG viewers. The images on their site are PNG and I've tried their sample code in both the latest version of firefox and inkscape but the image is not displayed correctly.

Thus, there's probably nothing wrong with your svg code, you just cannot expect it to be displayed correctly in every viewer. Try to find a programm that is capable of rendering 3D SVG and export a bitmap graphic, that's probably your only choice if you want to make your graphic viewable to a wider audience.

Comment: Currently we cannot achieve this effect that is seen in the png image?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. So browsers do not support this yet?

Comment: Yes, and I think it's a long way until they do. I'm developing a browser game that heavily relies on SVG images and unfortunatelly, there are many browsers that do not even support some of the rather basic features of SVG (like masking for instance). Most mobile browsers are amongst them, and even chrome does not support all the features I use. For these browsers I fall back to a php script that converts my dynamically created SVGs to PNG before displaying. SVG, unfortunatelly, seems to be far from being a universal standard on the web, and, with HTML5 canvases coming up, I doubt it ever will.

Comment: Has anything changed in the 6 months since this was posted?